# Swing: Bean parametrizer?

Tags: java, swing, javabeans

Is there Swing component, that lets me paramtrize my bean class?

**Example:**
Let's have bean class with 4 fields (so we have setters and getters). I want to generate Swing JTextFields + JLabels with field's names and then save it and create bean. It would resolve what kind of class should be created.

Has someone done this before?